# Cannot figure out why images stacking in ie7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

Go to: http://appointview.com/pricing in Internet Explorer (I am using version 9, but in the dev tools setting it to IE7 mode).

In the main body area the images are stacked, but should be floating left to right.

Comment: It would make it easier for people to help you if you post the specific code (HTML and CSS) for these elements so we can see what might be wrong.

Comment: I would not use "IE 7 mode" to test it; this is not 100% reliable.  Use the [free tools provided by MS](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575) to test in the actual browser versions.

Comment: I figured it would be easier to see the issue live, and then just use a browser debugger tool @sgroves. Recreating an example and throwing it in a fiddle I don't think would give a true example of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a matter of floating the elements left as well as having them set to inline-block